# Overview of all databases that exist in MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Some time back I setup a MySQL server on a Windows 2008 r2 server. Over the last year or two I've messed around and created several databases that Ive since forgotten the relevant credentials for.

The MySQL server is currently 5.6 and I have MYSQL Wordkbench CE installed.

How can I get an overview (and access to) of all the currently existing databases? I cant seem to find anything that explains how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that by running the DB in 'no password' mode disabled the databases, hence it was only showing me the servers schema rather than any databases.

Answer (score 1):

The following (my)sql-command will list all databases:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

Comment: Can i then interact with them from here? If so how?

Comment: You can select the database using `USE yourdatabase`.

Answer (score 1):

In **Edit/Preferences** choose **SQL Editor**.  In the **Sidebar** section select "Show Metadata and Internal Schemas".  Right-click the **Schemas** section and choose **Reset**.  The hidden Schemas will appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access you can simply view all databases on the server:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

If you don't have root access you can reset the root password. Instructions can be found in the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Comment: I tried that but all it shows me is a single column table of results with three schema in it. I cant seem to do anything with any of them.

Comment: @PhillHealey: What do you want to do with them? Use `USE yourdatabase` to select the database you want to work on.

Comment: Ok thanks. Essentially what im saying is, that its not showing up all the databases for some reason. I know more exist than are being shown, since some of them are in use.

Comment: It seems that by running the DB in 'no password' mode disabled the databases, hence it was only showing me the servers schema rather than any databases.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench shows you all schemas that your are allowed to see, that is, what the user you used to log-in has rights to see. There's no difference to the SHOW SCHEMAS (SHOW DATABASES) command. If you have a root user with full rights you should see all schemas in the left-hand schema tree.

[image]

Note: by default the internal schemas are not shown (mysql, I_S, P_S), but this can be changed in the preferences. If you don't see all the schemas you'd expect even with a root user then you may have changed the user's rights to something lower.